# Chrome extension development - open folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for company internal use, what i want to do is open folder in explorer (design folder at internal server) when someone add the project id in a textbox and click the button,

ex:

'Y:\design\' + siteNumber

Can i do it using javascript?

Thanks!
Nalinda

Answer (score 1):

No, javascript doesn't have access to the local machine's files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. You would need to write a stand-alone application in a native language (like C++ or Java) that could execute the opening of the folder, then have the Chrome extension communicate with it through the [NPAPI Plugin](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html). You *could* keep it all in Javascript by creating a Node.js program that executes the `open /path/to/folder` command (or your OS's equivalent). Either way, that native program would have to be pre-installed on the user's machine. But this doesn't seem like it should be a problem if it is an internal project.

Comment: Also keep an eye on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging.